# Page with ajax update does not remember state after pressing browser back button

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I have a page where an user favourites a book which updates the database using ajax (axios) and show an icon indicating the book has been favourited. The user clicks a link to view the list of their favourited books. The user returns to the book they favourited by pressing the back button in the browser.

The expected behaviour would be the user would see the icon indicating the book has been favourited but unless they reload the page, they see the initial page state (book was not yet favourited).

How can I make the page display the correct history state when the user clicks the back button?

```
<template>
  <button v-if="userHasBook(book.id)" v-on:click="removeFromFavourites">
    <span>Remove</span>
  </button>
  <button v-else v-on:click="addToFavourites">
    <span>Add</span>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['user', 'book'],
    data: function() {
        return {}
    },
    methods: {
        userHasBook(book_id){
            let $this = this;
            for (let book of $this.user.books){
                if (book.id === book_id){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
        removeFromFavourites(){
            let $this = this;
            $this.busy = true;
            $this.updateUserFavourite();
        },
        addToFavourites(){
            let $this = this;   
            $this.updateUserFavourite();
        },
        updateUserFavourite(){
            let $this = this;
            axios.put(`/api/books/user/${$this.user.id}/book/${$this.book.id}`).then(function(response){
                    $this.user.books = response.data;
                }).catch(function(){
            });
        },
        getUserBooks(){
            let $this = this;
            axios.get(`/api/books/user/${$this.user.id}`).then(function(response){
                $this.user.books = response.data;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        let $this = this;
        $this.getUserBooks();

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to load the data client-side, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB or use cookies

Comment: I recommend using vuex to easily manage your data inside the application. It's easier for you to share data among components and keep data when moving back and forth history.

Comment: @DatTran I would love to do that but I am very new to Vue so I have no clue how I would go on to achieve that unfortunately. Any pointers or examples would be great!

Comment: I think this example is good: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2018/04/vuejs-app-using-axios-vuex/. It includes how to use both vuex and vue-router (the way you navigate in you SPA)

Comment: @DatTran Thank you for that. I do not use Vue Router (using Vue with Laravel), so will I be able to use this approach even without Vue Router?

Comment: I don't have much experience using vue with laravel. But Vuex is stored on the client side memory. So that, if you make a new HTTP request (reload the page or change to different URL), the data in vuex will be reset. ANW, I found an example using them together. You can check it for more information: https://medium.com/js-dojo/using-vue-vuex-vue-router-with-laravel-2c0962c97416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using the History API to manipulate the URL every time the `updateUserFavourite` method is run. Here is the code for reference:

```
{
updateUserFavourite(){
            let $this = this;
            axios.put(`/api/books/user/${$this.user.id}/book/${$this.book.id}`).then(function(response){
                    $this.user.books = response.data;
                    $this.updateUrl(response.data);
                }).catch(function(){
            });
        },
updateUrl(data){
            if (history.pushState) {
                var newurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '?t=' + data.length  ;
                window.history.pushState({path: newurl}, '', newurl);
            }
        }
}
```